# Which chapter in the Bleach manga corresponds to the last episode in the anime?

Tags: bleach

I watched the Bleach anime first, and I heard that the continuation is only in the manga. So if it's possible, I'd like to know which chapter corresponds to the end of the anime to start reading. I don't want to dig through and reread the chapters which overlap with the anime.

Comment: Yes, the answer to this question (chapter 480) is already in both of those other questions, so while this is superficially a different question, for all intents and purposes it as a duplicate.